# How to do functional testing for multiple post API's using Soap UI

Tags: java, json, xml, groovy, soapui

Iam trying to execute multiple Post API's sequentially which is placed in Excel Sheet in Soap UI using Groovy script. I am Sharing Excel Please look into that.

Regards,
Anusha.

S.NO    Method  URL STATUS  RES_TIME    TIME_STAMP  JSON_Input
1      POST                                         Example.json
2      POST                                         Example1.json
3      POST                                         Example2.json
4      POST                                         Example3.json
5      POST                                         Example4.json
6      POST                                         Example5.json
7      POST                                         Example6.json
                                                    Example7.json

Comment: I think you need to look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please check the documentation or video's available in youtube.

Answer (score 0):

1. You will need jxl jar to read excel and you can download it from [jxl jar download](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjxljar.htm) link
2. Your excel must be saved in XLS format(Exel 97-2003 Workbook) for this code to work.

You can try this code below :

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import java.io.File
import java.io.IOException
import jxl.*
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException
import jxl.write.*
import jxl.write.Label


def reqOperationName = ""
def inputDataFileName = "D:/sample/temp1.xls"
def inputDataSheetName = "Sheet1"
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(inputDataFileName))
Sheet  sheet1 = workbook.getSheet(inputDataSheetName)

try{
    rowcount = sheet1.getRows()
    colcount = sheet1.getColumns()

    for(Row in 1..rowcount-1){

    reqOperationName = sheet1.getCell(1,Row).getContents()
    log.info reqOperationName
    //test the request
    testRunner.runTestStepByName(reqOperationName)
}


}
catch (Exception e) {log.info(e)}
finally{
    workbook.close()
}
```

This should work for your requirement. Let me know if it helps.